# Kendo Grid send extra parameters

Tags: kendo-ui

How can i send extra parameters on my GRID POST.

This is my tranport config:

```
transport: {
     read: {
     dataType: "json",
     url: "/user/list",
     type: "POST"
     }
}
```

I need to send a dynamic extra information ( especial filters XD).
I will set a script variable before any submit on grid.

Any Help?

Answer (score 10):

Question is discussed multiple times on the internet. You should use the [Data](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.read.data) function. [Here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-send-values-to-my-action-method-when-binding-the-grid?) is even more information. You can also pass the parameters directly to the **read** method of the dataSource.

```
 $('#myGrid').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.read({foo:42})
```

Comment: Is there a similar method for Create/Update/Destroy?

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra parameters using **Data("addParameter")**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Project.Models.UserModel>()
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(item => item.UserId).Title("UserId").Width(100);
    columns.Bound(item => item.UserName).Title("UserName").Width(200);
})
.Sortable()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Ajax()
.PageSize(5)
.Read(read => read.Action("list", "user").Data("addParameter"))
)

<script>
function addParameter()
    {
        return {
            UserId: 10 //Your value here
        };
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative to send parameters to the AJAX call, and also to log the Request and Response.

```
 read: function (options) {

            var jsonData = {
                "ID":          $('#ID').val(),         
                "ObjectType":  $('#dropObjectType :selected').val()
            };
            console.log("REQ: " + JSON.stringify(jsonData));

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/api/internal/SomeService",
                data: jsonData,
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log("RES: " + JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)));
```

You can also send the above `jsonData` in this way:

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read(jsonData);
```

And assign it to the `data:` (and log it):

```
read: function (options) {

        console.log("REQ: " + JSON.stringify(options.data));

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/api/internal/SomeService",
            data: options.data,
```